# How to check if the user is connected to the another site with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have two different websites. In the first one I have a user that creates an account and then connects. In the same site, I have a link that redirects to the other site.

I'd like to prevent copy paste of the second url. So I need to check if the user is connected to the first website. How can I do this ? Maybe with cookies but honestly I've been looking for this since this morning and nothing came to me.

Maybe I can put this to start

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms loginUrl="MYOTHERSITEURL" />
</authentication>
```

If someone as a answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to create an API on your login site, which your secondary site then can use to check if the user is authenticated. The primary site should then return the users data and the secondary site could then store this in a cookie.

Cookies can't be shared across different top level domains. However, if your sites are on the same top level domain and simply have different subdomains or similiar, then you can share cookies between them.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: I see what you mean. Unfortunatly i didn't made the first site. But there is a Api inside that manage login. I think the only way is to implement it on both site

Comment: If there's an API on the first site, on your primary site, you should make some sort of IsAuthenticated-method that will call to the first site and confirm the user is logged in, which, if the user is logged in, will store the user object in a cookie or session.

Comment: Yes i have to check this, it uses this dotnetopenauth to make the connection